# GWT + Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I need Google Maps API v3 calls in my GWT Project, more specifically an Autocomplete-Feature for Places like in Google-Maps and the DirectionServices.

We already tried 2 approaches to get v3 access, but none was satisfying:

1. [Using the GWT SuggestionBox Widget + Geocoder suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479603/suggest-addresses-in-a-suggestbox-in-gwt-java). This solution is very slow and even worser, the constraints you can put on the suggested Places is just country codes (e.g. "uk") and, even worse, it seems to be not working.
2. [Google Maps API v3 Wrapper for GWT done by branflake2267](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api). There seems to be a conflict between the wrapper and the already existing (older) GWT Google Maps API lib. When one tries to remove the Google GWT-maps-api from the project, severe changes would have to be made, since the structure of the API seems different (some Classes are not within the Wrapper).

Does somebody maybe had a similar problem and a solution for this? How can I get the Google Maps V3 API working in my GWT project?

Thank you very much guys for any help on this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an official port of Maps v3 supported by Google which can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip), but it is still in pre-release.

For more info, look at the comments of this [bug](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/issues/detail?id=381).

Comment: Thanks koma!

We will try that one and share our experiences as soon as we have them.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work. 
We used this port now, however it also required us to do severe code rewriting, but it seems there is not easier way to do it.

Comment: Your answer is outdated. The project is no longer maintained.

Comment: @kukis Any alternatives to Maps v3? :/

Comment: None that I heard off

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful with Maps v3 it has some serious issues when used with the latest GWTversions. It does not appear to use Overlays and uses ArrayHelper all of which cause problems on GWT 2.1 and up..

Comment: +1 and it's also not continued anymore unfortunately. But it seems it is the only library out there at the moment for GWT :/

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with the branflake API on GWT 2.8. However, it hasn't been updated in years and still uses API version 3.10. Unfortunately I'm going to have to either for it and take on maintaining my own version of it or find an alternative at some point.

For now, tho, it's still very much a usable solution.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.branflake2267/gwt-maps-api