# What's the best google Maps V3 API for GWT 2.5?

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a "working" API to work with google Maps in my new WebApp. The problem is: there are a plenty of third party libraries and I have tried some which did not work. Which one would you guys suggest?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the unreleased gwt teams library for maps?
It was pointed out in the answer to [GWT + Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11834578/459).

Answer (score 3):

The [branflake2267's](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Maps-V3-Api/commits/master) trunk has fixed a lot of errors, it's well maintained and it's good for production, I recommend it as the first option until google releases an oficial one (the 3.8.0-pre1 is a bit outdated and has some bugs).